# Pandas DataFrame - count 0s in every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe that looks like this

```
x = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2,0,4,0,6], 'B':[0, 0, 0, 44, 48, 81], 'C':[1,0,1,0,1,0]})
```

(assume it might have other columns).
I want to add a column, which specifies for each row, how many 0s there are in the specific columns A,B,C.

```
   A   B  C  num_zeros
0  1   0  1    1
1  2   0  0    2
2  0   0  1    2
3  4  44  0    1
4  0  48  1    1
5  6  81  0    1
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a boolean dtype dataframe using `==`, then use `sum` with `axis=1`:

```
x['num_zeros'] = (x == 0).sum(1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  num_zeros
0  1   0  1          1
1  2   0  0          2
2  0   0  1          2
3  4  44  0          1
4  0  48  1          1
5  6  81  0          1
```

Now, if you want explicitly define which columns, ie... on count in B and C columns, then you can use this:

```
x['Num_zeros_in_BC'] = (x == 0)[['B','C']].sum(1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  C  num_zeros  Num_zeros_in_BC
0  1   0  1          1                1
1  2   0  0          2                2
2  0   0  1          2                1
3  4  44  0          1                1
4  0  48  1          1                0
5  6  81  0          1                1
```

Comment: @BaronYugovich Would you consider accepting this solution if it helped you?